# How to overload == operator to see if two objects with a string vector are equal?

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I am writing a class named `StringSet` which has `vector<string> data` and `int length` as its private members.

```
bool StringSet::operator == (StringSet d)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == d.data[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I try calling this function like this,

```
StringSet doc1, doc2;
if (doc1 == doc2)
    {
        cout << "Both sentences are identical!\n";
    }
```

I get an assertion failure saying vector subscript out of range, I know what that means but I don't know how it implies here. If anyone can point out an obvious mistake I have made that would be great as I am a newbie to c++.

Comment: What if one `StringSet` object has a smaller length?

Comment: As @GBlodgett has said, you *first* need to check if the two 'length' values are the same. Also, I think you need to adjust your logic: as it is, you will get 'true' if **any one** of the vector element 'pairs' are equal.

Comment: `length` is redundant. `vector` has `.size()` method. To compare two vectors just use `data == d.data`.

Comment: Since a `vector<string>` maintains its own size, odds are your class isn't ensuring that `data.size() == length`.    Your loop will give undefined behavior if `length > data.size()`  OR `length > d.data.size()`, due to accessing non-existent elements of the vectors.  Without seeing a [mcve], we cannot ASSUME your code has correctly set `length` or `d.length` to ensure that your loop does not fall off the end of one of the vectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple

```
bool StringSet::operator == (const StringSet& d) const
{
  return data == d.data;
}
```

`std::vector` and `std::string` have already comparison operators, therefore you don't have to implement something special.